# Flutter - rounding border in opposite direction

Tags: flutter

I've found solution for this problem with help of [encubos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13222274/encubos) - thanks a lot! . May code can be simplified - if you resolve this in better way, please share your code.

CODE:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 1.0),
            top: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 1.0)
        )
      ),
      child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 0.0)
              ),
              height: 100,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 72,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 0.0),
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(
                      top: Radius.elliptical(150, 30),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ])
    ),
  ),
```

Result:

[image]

I've got problem with styling container bottom border. My goal is to rotate for 180 degrees bottom border of my top bar
[image]

Code:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(
          bottom: Radius.elliptical(150, 30)
        )),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new InkWell(
            child: new Text(
                'app',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 24
                )
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible way to solve this is using the same idea in your code, but applying it to the top part of a `Container` below

See this code and image.

You need to ajust the **color: white** and the **heights** of the containers

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.elliptical(150, 30),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    ])
```

[image]

Maybe you can improve this method and work from this.

Comment: that's will be ok but this white space is ruining rest of ui

Comment: As I said "You need to ajust the color: white". Replace white with your background color. Also adjust the height.